# Golang, csv.writer.write 20k rows into CSV freeze my PC

Tags: csv, go

I have an issue on Linux Ubuntu with 1.4.2, which I am not sure how to sort:

```
func main() {
        dir, _ := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
        outputFile, outputError := os.OpenFile(dir+"/out1.csv",
                os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
        if outputError != nil {
                fmt.Printf("An error occurred with file creation\n")
                return
        }
        defer outputFile.Close()
        writer := csv.NewWriter(outputFile)
        results := getResults()
        for _, result := range results {
                writer.Write([]string{result.Item, result.Price, result.Shipping})
        }
        writer.Flush()
}
```

when `results` is 1000+ records my PC freezes for seconds and when it's say 20k, it freezes for minutes.
How do I solve such an issue in a proper way? 
I though to flush it every N records, and add `time.Sleep` – but that looks awkward…

Comment: What OS? What Go version? What is `file` (i.e. is it an `*os.File` or a `bufio.Reader`; is it to the network or a local filesystem or a LAN filesystem.

Comment: For 1,000,000 (one million) records, my program took `real 0m11.128s`, `user 0m9.148s` and `sys 0m0.316s`. Give us a reproducible example: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have edited top post. Thank you!

Comment: I have no idea what `getResults` does. Are you certain the problem isn't there?

Comment: Never ignore errors; does `writer.Write` return a non-nil error?

Comment: yes :-(  it seems like problem somewhere else,  I just made a simple function to write 10000 records and it was  milliseconds...  

I will now see what writer.Write returns.

Comment: @peterSO, that's slow, mine took 1.84s totsl to compile, generate 1e6 random results (740ms), and write to a new file (940ms) ;-). For 10e6 it took 17.4s (7.63s+9.53s). (Sorry, I know such numbers are irrelevant, [but I couldn't resist](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-banter-over-Air-Traffic-Control).)

Comment: When you find out what happened please update :-).

Comment: yes... I trying to figure... Problem that getRusults() is complicated and take hours to finish, and I know that it returned fine, but then when it starting to write, it freezes for some time... No error on writer.Write... I thinking now, that could be thing with my PC. I will check it up and reports here.

Comment: I figured what it was, it was libxml via Gokogiri eating my RAM by gigabytes, and when it was ready to write CSV the memory was kind of full, and all of these cause the freezing effect. I tried various suggestions but nothing worked as I needed, so I  switched to cascadia and regex... That was solution. Goquery is also option, but I didnt tried that.